# digital computer hud in javascript

Tags: javascript, animation

is it possible to do something like this in javascript: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7hEHRoq080

I'm not sure, but i'd think you'd have to use a canvas. if it is REMOTELY possible, what tools are available to do such a thing. Would I need a tweening library?

I know I could just create a video and show that, but I wanted the experience to seem seamless, and without the need for any kind of plugin.

Comment: Plugins aren't needed to show video in modern browsers.

Comment: for one, not everyone uses "modern browsers" and not even IE9 is compliant enough to be able to rely users having at least that version. secondly, I want to use just javascript

Comment: You could probably do it with the HTML5 canvas element and javascript. I'm not sure but I think it should be possible.

Comment: IE9 supports both HTML5 video and canvas. Don't suggest canvas if you need to support non-modern browsers, because only modern browsers support it.